# How to extract a part of a formula and copy it into a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with a formula in one cell:

`=[file1_January-2015.xls]Sheet1!A1+[file2_January-2015.xls]Sheet1!A1`

I need to write a macro, that extract the `January-2015` part and change it into... next month. So if there is `December-2015` it should change it to `January-2016`.
I don't know how to extract a part of a formula and copy it into a variable...

Comment: Welcome to SO, have you writen any code yet to try to solve your problem? If so please post this and explain where the problem occurs. If not SO is not a website to request code i would suggest google to search for examples or a help forum. SO is a website for Q/A about problems or errors in code made by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering myself.

I wrote almost that what I needed. It works when a month is a number "01", "02", ..., "12". So it works when a formula is `=[file1_01-2015.xls]Sheet1!A1`

```
Sub change_path_in_a_formula()

    Dim cell As String
    cell = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

    Dim month As Integer
    month = Mid(cell, 9, 2)

    Dim change_year As Byte
    If month = 12 Then change_year = 1

    Dim year As Integer
    year = Mid(cell, 12, 4) + change_year
    month = (month Mod 12) + 1

    Dim zero_month As String
    If month < 10 Then zero_month = "0"

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
       Left(cell, 8) & zero_month & month & _
       Mid(cell, 11, 1) & _
       year & Mid(cell, 16, Len(cell) - 15)

End Sub
```

Comment: I had been thinking about this so I'll just mention that you need to establish the maximum month and year and work backwards. You can change Feb to Mar then Jan to Feb but if you try it the other way around, you will end up overwriting your previous alterations. Also, picking one date/filename format and sticking with it is paramount. It's hard to hit a moving target.